# Make Intersection Observer more precise and performant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

#### Background

I am using the Intersection Observer in my React app to keep track on which category I'm on while scrolling through the page. I'd like to *observe* the div that is closest to the menubar.

#### Make it more precise

To better visualize this I took a small screen recording. You can see that it switches between "Signature" and "Baser", not randomly, but not at the way I want it to switch. I'd like it to switch to the other item in my menubar when the div is almost aligned to the menubar.

My screen recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZF8qbLAQhWQ

#### How to handle performance

Since I am using React I will be updating a state when I want to update the active menu item when I scroll through the page. For this, I am using their new hooks API.

```js
//page height: 1140
//observerMargin: 570
const observerMargin = Math.floor(pageHeight / 2);
const observerConfig = {
    rootMargin: `-${
        pageHeight % 2 === 0 ? observerMargin - 1 : observerMargin
    }px 0px -${observerMargin}px 0px`
};

useEffect(() => {
    const handleIntersection = function(entries) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.target.id !== activeMenuProdCatId && entry.isIntersecting) {
                setActiveMenuProdCatId(entry.target.id); // setting the state here
            }
        });
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, observerConfig);
    observer.observe(refs[menuProductCategory.name].current);

    return () => observer.disconnect();
}, [activeMenuProdCatId, setActiveMenuProdCatId, observerMargin, refs, pageHeight]);
```

I made a function that creates a ref for each div I want to observe, it will be determined by the length of `menuProductCategories` length :

```js
const refs = activeMenu.menuProductCategories.reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.name] = createRef();
    return acc;
}, {});
```

And in my JSX I give each of my div a ref and an id:

```
<div
    id={menuProductCategory.id}
    ref={refs[menuProductCategory.name]}
>
    ...
</div>
```

When doing this on my PC it works fine, but in mobile, it lags when I scroll through the page fast.

These are the problems I am facing and I'm hoping to get some guidance. I also hope I've been descriptive enough, otherwise, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: If the code you have works, and you're willing to share all of it (enough to reproduce the behavior fully), this *might* be on topic on [codereview.se], but you'll want to review [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) and their help center to ensure it is on topic.